# How to add timestamp in Postman request?

Tags: timestamp, postman

I want to add two timestamps to a post request in Postman. The first is for Local-time and the second for GMT time. Both should be formatted as `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`.

The following script displays the date and time as "2017-06-28T08:51:29", but I want the date in simple numbers.

```js
postman.setGlobalVariable('timestampUtcIso8601', (new Date()).toISOString());
```

I tried formatting the date myself, but it didn't work:

```js
var time = date.getTime();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("currentTime", date);
```

How can I get the date for local and GMT in a `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` format? Does Postman have built-in functionality for formatting the time and date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried with `.replace()`?
Something like `date.replace(/-|:|T/g,"")` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for reply...and nice trick.

But I'm getting this value "2017-07-11T12:20:38.424Z"....now problem is last four characters after decimal point. I want to remove those also, so that it will be in this format YYYYMMDDhhmmss.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I used  date.slice(0,-4); to remove last 4 characters from timestamp.
Thanks @Klubi

Comment: @klubi, how did you use the .replace() method? can you write down the code snippet please?

Comment: @hirosht ex. `globals['aaa'].replace(/https:\/\/(.*?)\./,'https://login.');`
this one replaces any subdomain with `https://login.`

Comment: @klubi, Im getting the "2017-11-08T09:22:29.022Z" from var time = (new Date()).toISOString().

I am in need of replace just the colons (:) with (-).

how should I use the content in replace method for it? kind assistance please?

Comment: @hirosht `time.replace(/:/g,'-')`, this may be helpful-> https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99464

Answer (score 4):

Check out the PostMan github page issues:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/553

Moment.js (without locales) is available in Postman v5.1.2 and above, do go ahead and check it out. You can use moment in your scripts as follows:

```
var moment = require('moment');

moment('2017-01-01T10:10:10.000').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') // January 1st 2017, 10:10:10 am
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple put following code in you postman prequest

```
var moment = require('moment')
 pm.globals.set("CurrentDatetime", moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD"))
```

and add that variable in your request

```
        "ReqDate": {{CurrentDatetime}}",
```

This way is adding time in ISO format but not in my local timezone. How can I change it to local time zone?

Comment: use `.format("yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS-05:00")`
You can change the timezone at the end as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Local time:

```
const moment = require('moment');

pm.environment.set("currentDateTime", moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss"));
```

GMT:

```
const moment = require('moment');    
pm.environment.set("currentDateTime",moment().utc().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss"));
```